# Select common rows across different years

Tags: r, filter, group-by, tidyverse

I have a very large dataframe containing 150,000 rows and 1,000 ID values, across 20 years. I want to keep all the rows that have common ID value across different years.

```
x <- structure(list(ID = c(2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5), Julian = c(40749, 41425, 
40749, 41057, 40735, 40743), Year = c(2011, 2012, 2011, 2012, 
2011, 2012), Location = c("8300", "Hatchery", "6950", "Hatchery", 
"8300", "11025"), Distance = c(39625, 31325, 38625, 31325, 39650, 
42350)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))


x
#   ID Julian Year Location Distance
# 1  2  40749 2011     8300    39625
# 2  2  41425 2013 Hatchery    31325
# 3  3  40749 2011     6950    38625
# 4  3  41057 2012 Hatchery    31325
# 5  6  40735 2011     8300    39650
# 6 12  40743 2011    11025    42350
```

Comment: Something is wrong with your data, try again: `dput(mydata)` and what is the expected output for this example input data.

Comment: Great, what is the expected output, which rows would you keep in this example data?

Comment: Expected output: ID = 2 &3 should be kept, but ID = 6&12 should be dropped becasuse they only appear in one year.

Comment: @gladys_c_hugh thanks for your help, but it's not quite what I am looking for. And I haven't downvoted you answer btw!

Comment: @zx8754 For example some of the ID's appear in 18 years from 20. I want to drop them too and only keep the ones that apear across 20 years.

Comment: Then replace that 1 in my answer with any number you wish.

Answer (score 3):

Group by ID and check if they appear in more than one year:

```
x %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   filter(length(unique(Year)) > 1)
   
# # A tibble: 4 × 5
# # Groups:   ID [2]
#      ID Julian  Year Location Distance
#   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
# 1     2  40749  2011 8300        39625
# 2     2  41425  2013 Hatchery    31325
# 3     3  40749  2011 6950        38625
# 4     3  41057  2012 Hatchery    31325
```

Answer (score -1):

Not quite clear what you mean by "keep all the rows that have common ID value across different years."

It sounds a little like you want to keep all the rows where there's more than one of the same ID value in the whole table, which is quite easy:

```
structure(list(ID = c(2, 2, 3, 3, 6, 12), 
             Julian = c(40749, 41425, 40749, 41057, 40735, 40743), 
             Year = c(2011, 2013, 2011, 2012, 2011, 2011), 
             Location = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L)),
             Distance = c(39625, 31325, 38625, 31325, 39650, 42350)), 
        class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L)) |> 
add_count(ID) |> 
filter(n > 1)
```

with `library(tidyverse)`

But that's suspicously straight-forward, so perhaps you could expound a little if the above hasn't provided a solution.

EDIT: this gives the output:

```
  ID Julian Year Location Distance n
1  2  40749 2011        3    39625 2
2  2  41425 2013        1    31325 2
3  3  40749 2011        2    38625 2
4  3  41057 2012        1    31325 2
```

Comment: `"across different years"` if ID 2 had Years 2011 and 2011, this solution would be wrong.

Comment: ah got it - I'm being thick